# pip install or any other directory doesn't work, no matter what I try

Tags: python, syntax, pip, installation

I ve tried ever IDE so far.
Downloaded Python and now trying to download some modules and libraries.
Trying to download Pillow with PIP.
Whatever I try, seems that i am totally dumb.
I type: "python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip" its "invalid syntax".
Same whatever I type.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are trying to use to upgrade pip doesn't work for me either. I would recommend trying this one: `pip install --upgrade pip`

After doing that you may freely use commands like
`pip install library_name` on whatever you want.

The other possible problem may be that you have to specify the version of pip you are trying to use. This is done by typing `pip3` or `pip3.7` (depending on the version of python) instead of just `pip`.

You may use `python --version` to check which version are you on.

If none of the commands involving `pip` work for you, you should reinstall/update python without removing a tick from "install pip" or make sure that it is installed in the proper place, because I sometimes had a problem, when pip worked in PowerShell, but did not in CMD.

Comment: You can also see what you have installed with "pip list".